# DataAnnotation [Index(IsUnique = true)] on a column throws error Attribute 'Index' is not valid on this declaration type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, data-annotations

This is my first time exploring DataAnnotations (I was hoping to use this over fluent)...and I don't understand why the following code throws a compile time error:

*CS0592 - Attribute 'Index' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'class' declaration*

```
public class Holiday
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is to make the `Date` column UNIQUE...and I thought using `[Index(IsUnique = true)]` on a column is the correct way to make it unique...but it is not allowing me to use the Index attribute on columns, only on classes...

Please teach me how to achieve this?

Comment: In addition to using data annotations, you can also use FluentApi to configure.`builder.Entity<Holiday>().HasIndex(b => b.Date).IsUnique();`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, the [`Index`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.indexattribute?view=efcore-5.0) attribute  is the data annotation equivalent of [`HasIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder.hasindex?view=efcore-5.0) fluent API, and simlar to the API, is intended to be applied at entity (class) level, providing the *properties which constitute the index, in order*, plus other information like the index name, whether it is unique etc.

So in your case you'd need something like this

```
[Index(nameof(Holiday.Date), IsUnique = true)]
public class Holiday
{
    // ...
}
```

which corresponds to the following fluent configuration

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Holiday>()
    .HasIndex(e => e.Date)
    .IsUnique();
```

Actually all this is well explained with examples in the [Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations) section of the official EF Core documentation.

Comment: Ohhhhhh so that's how you use `Index` attribute, thank you very very @IvanStoev by the way, if I'd like to make both `Date` and `Name` to be unique, I will add many class `Index` attributes to the class right? I can add both `[Index(nameof(Holiday.Date), IsUnique = true)]` and `[Index(nameof(Holiday.Name), IsUnique = true)]` ?

Comment: @GAC If you want to have separate indexes (unique or not), yes, you will use separate attributes (`Index` attribute allows multiple). If you want a combination of two or more fields (a.k.a composite index), then you'd use one attribute with field list.

Comment: Actually all this is less well explained with examples if you end up in the EF6 [Data Annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations#index) section of the official EF documentation. The documentation here can be a bit confusing ;)